# How can I load previous data and continue adding to its value (numbers/int) using buttons?

Tags: java, android

I'm new here and new to android studio, hope you can help me.

I am trying to make a simple counter app.

I have a button that adds +1 to the value of my textview(int) and a button that saves that value to shared preferences, and another button that loads the value from shared preferences, and they all work fine. I ran into problem when I first open the app and add some values to textview, then click save, and reload the app. After that when I click "load" button it loads the value fine, but when I then click "Add" button it starts counting from 0 again and it overwrites the loaded value in textview, the counting starts again...
What I want to do is after reloading the app, the counting to continue from loaded value from sp.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {

Button btnReset, btnPlus, btnSave, btnLoad;
TextView tv;

int counter;

String stringVal;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadSavedPreferences();

    initialiseUI();
}

private void savePreferences(int score) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("score", score);
    editor.commit();
}

private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    try {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        int counter = sharedPreferences.getInt("score", 0); 
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(counter)); 
    }
    catch (Exception a)
    {
        //Hevi
    }
}

private void initialiseUI() {

    loadSavedPreferences();

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btnLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);
    btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            loadSavedPreferences();
        }
    });

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            savePreferences(counter);
        }
    });

    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter=0;

            stringVal = Integer.toString(counter);
            tv.setText(stringVal);

            savePreferences(counter);
        }
    });

    btnPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            counter++;
            stringVal = Integer.toString(counter);
            tv.setText(stringVal);

        }
    });
}
```

Also I would like better if I could load the saved value from sp on startup, without using the button, I tried that but was unsuccessful so I made the button and it worked.
But I would prefer better if I can erase the button and do it without it.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

**Step 1.** Change the code from

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadSavedPreferences();
    initialiseUI();
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialiseUI();
    loadSavedPreferences();
}
```

**Step 2.** Change the code from

```
int counter = sharedPreferences.getInt("score", 0);
```

to

```
counter = sharedPreferences.getInt("score", 0);
```